# Disable One Drive Text Editor's typing suggestions

Tags: onedrive

These are pretty annoying, especially because being less than accurate:

[image]

Is there any way I can totally disable writing suggestions in One Drive's Text Editor?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that there's a way to disable this. I couldn't find one and [this MS Community topic](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/onedrive-online-text-editor-disable-predictive/40a6a902-812d-4dee-982f-464e51a71393) agrees.

Comment: Two things that you might find helpful though: 1) You may use `Shift+Esc` to dismiss the suggestions. 2) If using OneDrive's Text Editor is crucial to you, consider submitting a feature request [here](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/913528) or [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/newthread?threadtype=Questions&cancelurl=%2Fen-us%2Fmsoffice%2Fforum&forum=msoffice&filter=msoffice_drive) and hopefully, it'll be considered.